# Firefox Group Tabs: Will my non-active groups be able to receive messages and do Ajax requests?

Tags: firefox

I started using group tabs recently, but I couldn't find out if I would be able to receive messages in non active groups. Let me explain it with an example.

Group "work" is the group of tabs I'm currently working in.
Group "fun" is the group, where I'm running eBuddy, a web MSN client. This group is currently non-active because I'm working in the group "work".

So if somebody sent me a message on MSN, will I be able to get that and hear the sound, for example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is "yes" for Firefox 4 and 5 and "no" beyond.  My only evidence is [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595601).